# Verb describing "opening" a new research field

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm seaking a single verb which describes the incetpion/invention/introduction of a new research field. Example usage:

> Psychology and Complex-systems are two research fields that were established as indepednent research domains during the 20th century.  However, apart from anacdotal examples, the two domains were not substantially mixed.
>
> The current work should signify the **opening** of a new research field, which we term "Complex-Psychology", by a particular amalgamation of the two disciplines.

"We wish to *introduce* the new field" might be a good choice, but I'm looking to stress the active role of the writers in the creation of somthing that did not exist before and is now created/invented.

Comment: emergence of a new research field

Comment: Your slashes are leaning the wrong direction. English only uses / never \, you know.

Comment: @tchrist I actually did not know that :) 
Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Emily's answer has been downvoted, possibly for lack of references, but I can't think of anything better than 'establish'.

Comment: "Founded" or "Established" or "Pioneered" all seem better than the answers I've see so far.  but .. this is a naming game (guess Emily had established on her list) "Founding", "Pioneering"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**inaugurate**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inaugurate)

Initial; first vb (tr)
to commence officially or formally; initiate
to place in office formally and ceremonially; induct
*to open ceremonially; dedicate formally*

As in:

> "We wish to inaugurate the new research field X"

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas: conceive, generate, establish, create.

We wish to establish a new field...

Comment: Please could you try to expand this a little, and perhaps pick one as a favourite? Otherwise it’s just a laundry list (although some questions do rather beg for one ...).

Answer (score -1):

A "seminal" or "germinal" work or field of study.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Seminal+work